# How can I fix the beam.smp memory usage?

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I am using celery and rabbitmq for background jobs. while running a program my memory consumption is increasing. after some time the this the error is shown

```
[2014-08-06 05:17:21,036: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 6.00 seconds...
```

so I try following commands to reset the rabbitmq

```
sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app
sudo rabbitmqctl reset
sudo rabbitmqctl start_app
```

The output of

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

Displayed many queues as below (I have shown some)

```
febe4fe719304333a328d42c4411b187    1
febf40b7b30d46a7a0f8b1e8ef5805ab    1
fec87e8405f54495b8dafc78fc2a7427    1
fedb1199f2f34b6ab5cd9d8c1fc0bbef    1
fedf56dc300b4947b1b9d635e3cb19d5    1
fee5531554b04ccab4d153d892af09a0    1
feec17f521454670834e2e5857416812    1
feee69f5159e48399d7769caacd13247    1
feeea6673ce24fdabfbdaf4cd8a489fd    1
feefc5513f1c449da8fc3be7d6cdb7fa    1
fef552daca104dfaa0a2c5ca262c3fcc    1
fef787753b854eee8e584dd5c3d848d5    1
fef80b363eda46269bb4fbb25735e935    1
fefaf812be4d4e15b5aec462a00a97b5    1
fefb039627f14499955adc9513d17ac8    1
fefcd7a6f1e142679b05e764fb88f777    1
feff3d981bf14d5383f8d9e337a3fb87    1
ff018eb196ae4ab8af65f79071c76fa6    1
ff044d8426b246b4a93dad363f76c05f    1
ff04ccfd8ff74ba4b5284845bd1d3e87    1
ff075b85ec274022b276cdf47c2db578    1
```

I have tried following settings is celery config file

```
app.conf.update(

    task_ignore_result=True,
    task_store_errors_even_if_ignored = False,
    worker_enable_remote_control=False,
    accept_content = ['json'],
    task_serializer = 'json',
    result_serializer = 'json',
    result_persistent=False,
    result_expires=60
)
```

Still, I'm facing the same issue.